# Can't Start Rails Server, ActiveAdmin Probably Has Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I installed ActiveAdmin to manage the Admin end of my Rails app and everything was absolutely fine till I generated a model for ActiveAdmin. Now the rails server fails to start, even `Rake` Rollback or `rails d active_admin:resource MyModel` doesn't work. I am clueless now, might be a simple stupid error but still I can't figure it out, BTW here's the error dump.

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/admin/products.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Products (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:216:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/error.rb:41:in `capture'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:216:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `block in load!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `load!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:230:in `routes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: i'm guessing the model you generated is `Product` not `Products` ?

Comment: @sa77 Yup I generated model Products

Comment: then you need to create your model class as `product.rb` with `class Product < ActiveRecord::Base; end`

Comment: @sa77 Yup, that fixed it, :P Thanks man!